# How to get the index of an item added dynamically to a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I would like to get the current index of an item in a listbox that was added dynamically. Essentially my item is a HubTile, and hubtiles are added on a click event one at a time. The collection of hubtile items are held in an ObservableCollection. This observablecolelction is bound to a listbox which displays the items. To illustrate, what I have is as follows:

TabsPage.xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="tileList" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:HubTile Title="{Binding TileName}" Margin="6"
                                         Notification="{Binding Notification}"
                                         DisplayNotification="{Binding DisplayNotification}"
                                         Message="{Binding Message}"
                                         GroupTag="{Binding GroupTag}"
                                         Source="{Binding ImageUri}"
                                         Tap="hubTile_Tap">
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu">
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="MenuItem_Tap"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete" Tap="deleteMenuItem_Tap"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:HubTile>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

TabsPage.xaml.cs

```
ObservableCollection<TileItem> tileItems;

public TabsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateTileList(); //starts the list of HubTiles with a single main tile
    }

private void CreateTileList()
    {
        tileItems = new ObservableCollection<TileItem>()             
        {            
            //TileItem is     
            new TileItem() { ImageUri = mainImage, Title = "main", /*Notification = "",*/ Message = "main", GroupTag = "MainGroup", TileName = "main" },

        };

        //Set the first tile item
        this.tileList.ItemsSource = tileItems;  //sets the tileList Listbox ItemsSource to the tileItems ObservableCollection            

    }

void addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage newTileImage = new BitmapImage();

        var newItem = new TileItem() { ImageUri = newTileImage, Title = "new", /*Notification = "",*/ Message = "new HubTile", GroupTag = "TileGroup", TileName = "new" };
        tileItems.Add(newItem); //update UI immediately and add to collection
    }

private void hubTile_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //how to get the current index of the tapped HubTile//
        //var tap = (((sender as HubTile).Parent as ListBox).SelectedIndex); //NullReferenceException thrown
    }
```

So, the HubTile items are correctly added to the UI, but on the tapped event I do not know how to get the selected index of the currently tapped HubTile item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DataContext of the item clicked like such

```
private void hubTile_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    TileItem item = (TileItem)element.DataContext;
    int index = tileItems.IndexOf(item);
    // Use the index
}
```

You can also subscribe to the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox instead of the Tap event of the Hubtile. Then in the Selectionchanged event you can get the index.

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        int index = tileList.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the tileItems a public property and bind to it in XAML it as the source.

Add a public int and bind the path to it as the SelectedIndex

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rules}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
```